# FB batch request : get Profil Images of managed Pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, batch-file, fbconnect

Hi there i tried to get all the Profile-Images of the Pages i managed.
I tried something like this:

> // my loop:

```
$request[] = array(
                 'method' => 'POST',
                 'relative_url' => '/'.$account->id.'/?fields=picture.type(large)&access_token='.$account->access_token.''
             );
```

and then:

```
  $batchResponse = $this->facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($request),'POST',array('access_token' => $this->facebook->getAccessToken()));
```

without success :/

i also tried to set the access_token of the page in the body tag:

```
    $request[] = array(
       'method' => 'POST',
       'relative_url' => '/'.$account->id.'/?fields=picture.type(large)'
       'body' => '&access_token='.$account->access_token.''
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [PHP script should have you login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/). If the login was successful, the SDK will manage the access_token for you.

Then issue this one request:

```
$result = $this->facebook->api('/me/accounts?fields=name,picture.type(large)', 'GET');
```

If you don't want to authenticate, instead you can pass an array of ids:

```
$page_ids = array( _PAGE_ID_1, _PAGE_ID_2, ...);
$result = $this->facebook->api('/?ids=' . implode(',',$page_ids) . '&fields=name,picture.type(large)', 'GET');
```

For these queries, you are *getting* data, so you should be using a `GET` request. Within the Facebook API, `POST` requests are only used when you are sending data to Facebook.